# Layout Advice for C#

Tags: c#

I'm having a difficult time on this issue. I've searched on this site and couldn't find a solution anywhere yet. I have to make a grid of blocks to be displayed on a picture. I've searched and found things about drawing the grid and the GridView class. But all that seems impossible since I have to manipulate the size of the blocks to whatever size. So if anyone can provide any advice I would be very grateful thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need simple grid, you can do it by simply drawing it to image:

```
using (var bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\darbai_test\Penguins.jpg")) 
{
  var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
  var xStep = 10;
  var yStep = 15;
  for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width / xStep; i++)
  {
    var x = i * xStep;
    graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, 0, x, bitmap.Height);
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height / yStep; j++)
  {
     var y = j * yStep;
     graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, y, bitmap.Width, y);
  } 

  bitmap.Save(@"c:\darbai_test\penguins_withgrid.jpg");
}
```

Comment: will that allow me to change the size of the blocks as well

Comment: block size is defined by xStep and yStep variables

Comment: it reaches a exception when the code reaches bitmap.save so I cant see the results yet

Comment: Never mind the file couldn't over write it had the same name. Thanks alot so much I'm in your debt